# How would dragons utilize ships?

Tags: dragons, flight, shipbuilding

I'm writing a fantasy novel with a race of intelligent and technologically advanced dragons. now, if we pretend that they can somehow fly, **How would they utilize boats and ships in order to traverse oceans?**

Comment: Quetzalcoatlus was a colossal pterosaur that could probably fly across seas in long journeys. Problem is a group of quetzalcoatlus would definitely be capable of only carrying a fraction of that they'd be able to transport if they were in a large ship, although they'd travel much more slowly.

Comment: exactly, the purpose of ships for them would be for transporting cargo and supplies. more of a hub for a group of dragons, from which solo flights could be taken.

Comment: Aircraft carriers. Also, where else are are they going to keep their cool dragon stuff?

Comment: Check out the Temeraire books by Naomi Novik, staring with "His Majesty's Dragon".  They're historic fantasy, set in the Napoleonic era, but with dragons.  "Dragon carrier" ships are a thing that feature in some of the books for long ocean voyages.

Comment: I'm almost disappointed that you clarified your question in the main body of the text. "_How would dragons utilize ships?_" as a sort of in-flight meal on a long-haul trip, I imagine...

Comment: @StarfishPrime yes, I would imagine! unfortunately, there are no humanoids in this world, so I guess they'll have to settle for floating ocean hotels instead, complete with bed and breakfast..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the ship buys them something of more value than traveling the same distance, flying, the dragons will have an advantage in using ships.

Some possibilities:

- Cargo.  This one may simply be better than flight; the water provides the buoyancy, and the ship just has to move forward.  A dragon would have to lift the cargo as well as fly it.
- Less work.  Flight is calorie intensive.  A ship gets its motion from air or an engine.  Or even from being rowed; buoyancy means that dragon rowers just have to move the ship forward, not keep it in the air, which may easily counter-balance the weight of the ship.  This means they need less food or can do more work.
- Time.  Bask in the sun and contemplate great plans with the thoughts that would otherwise have to be expended keeping track of air currents and looking for downdrafts.
- Safety.  A ship can be shipwrecked, of course, or blown off course, but this is aggravated in the air.

Comment: Boats for oceans and wagons for land. Just because you can fly doesn’t mean you *want* to!